# sqlite3 not found error in android shell

Tags: android, android-studio

I am going to `adb shell` (with root privileges) in my android.
When I am trying to run -

```
sqlite3 my.db
sh: sqlite3 not found
```

I also checked if sqlite3 exists or not by doing -

```
cd /system/xbin
ls -lrt | grep "sqlite3"
```

And sqlite3 is there. Why I am not able to execute it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`/system/xbin` presumably is not in the `PATH`.

Comment: I did that also -
`cd /system/xbin,
sqlite3 my.db,
sh: sqlite3 not found`

Comment: @iamsmith41: In macOS and Linux, to run a command in the current working directory, use `./`: `./sqlite3 my.db`. Since Android is Linux-based, the same rule holds for its shell.

Comment: Thanks, Job done.  Such a small thing, knowing but missing. :)